# perl given-when structure syntax error

Tags: perl

I'm trying using the given-when structure to write a little number-guessing program but my terminal keeps giving me syntax errors, anybody have any idea what could go wrong?

```
use strict;
my $secret = int(1 + rand 100);
my $flag = 0;
my $guess;
print "Here\n";
while($flag == 0){
    print "Please guess a number:\n";
    chomp($guess = <STDIN>);
    given($guess){ #-------------- line 13
        when($_ < $secret){print "Too Low\n"}
        when($_ > $secret){print "Too High\n"}
        when($_ == $secret){print "You've guessd it!";$flag = 1}
        default {print "User chose to exit";$flag = 1}
    }
}
```

Error message:

> syntax error at ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 13, near "){" syntax
>   error at ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 15, near "){" syntax error at
>   ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 16, near ";}" syntax error at
>   ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 17, near ";}" Execution of
>   ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: It works fine if you add `use feature qw(switch)`. See [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements) for more information

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine if you add `use feature 'switch'` at the top of your program.

From [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements):

> **Switch Statements**
>   Starting from Perl 5.10.1, you can say
>
> ```
> use feature 'switch';
> ```
>
> to enable an experimental switch feature.
>   Under the "switch" feature, Perl gains the experimental keywords `given`,
>   `when` , `default`, `continue`, and `break`. Starting from Perl 5.16, one can
>   prefix the switch keywords with `CORE::` to access the feature without a 
>   `use feature` statement.

**Note**:

Adding `use feature 'switch'` will let run your program without syntax errors, but you still can get warnings like these:

```
given is experimental at ./test.pl line 16.
when is experimental at ./test.pl line 17.
```

The reason is that `given` and `when` use the experimental smartmatch operator. See blog post [Experimental features now warn (reaching back to v5.10)](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2013/06/experimental-features-now-warn-reaching-back-to-v5-10/) of `The Effective Perler` for good examples and more information.

To turn off these warnings you can add

```
no warnings 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

after the `use feature 'switch'` statement. However, note that these kind of warnings was added in Perl 5.18, so if you plan to run the code on an earlier Perl version, you should use

```
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings => 'experimental::smartmatch';
```

instead to avoid a `"Unknown warnings category"` failure.

Finally, all these consideration can be handled more easily by using the  [experimental](https://metacpan.org/pod/experimental) pragma instead, and 
 replace `use feature 'switch'` with:

```
use experimental 'switch';
```

The latter should enable the feature and switch off warnings in one statement.

Comment: Thx! I just checked I'm using "This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2(v5.18.2), even if I add use feature "switch";  at the beginning I still get given is experimental at ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 13.
when is experimental at ./Learning_perl_chapt15.pl line 14. but at least the program can run without syntax error now

Comment: (Better yet, don't use a feature that's very likely to stop working)

Comment: @ikegami Re: `"You actually need no if $] >= 5.018..."`: Strange, I get `Unknown warnings category 'experimental::switch'` when using this construct (I am using perl version 5.20.2). Also, the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) claims there is no such category.

Comment: @ikegami Actually it turned out to be  `"experimental::smartmatch"` and not `"experimental::switch"`, see my updated answer.